# Expandable element gets closed itself with single click

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, webdriverwait

I have a div that has a even listener linked with it. The div expands with a single click and exposes some more buttons. I am trying to open the div with a click and then clicking on the exposed button. But when I am executing the test the div gets clicked, expanded to expose additional buttons and then collapses on its own. However if doing manually it will only collapse if clicked twice. So then when I try to click on the exposed button it could not be found and I get: following errors interchangeable.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

or

```
Element is not clickable at point . Other element would receive the click
```

I guess probably event listener attached has a role in this by either loading too fast/slow. Looks like other elements are overlapping the target element. How can I click the target button.

I have tried giving it a sleep time of 2 seconds between when I click the div and the target button but it seems that as soon as the div element is clicked it gets expanded and collapses at the same time. I could see it doing that.
I also tried using below code:
    `driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)`

Here is the html code snippet:

```
   <div class="software-package-top" id="package2_toggle">

     <div class="software-package-info">
       <div class="software-package-name">
     name      </div>
       <div class="software-package-version">
         &nbsp;3.0.1      </div>
       <div class="software-package-status">
                 <span class="software-package-enabled">Disabled</span>&nbsp;&nbsp;<span class="software-package-not-running">Not Running</span>              </div>
     </div>
         <div class="software-package-arrow"></div>
       </div>
     <div class="software-package-details software-hidden" id="package2_controls" style="display: none;">
   <div class="software-package-description">
 </div>

 <hr>
 <div class="software-package-controls">
 <input type="button" name="View Release Notes" value="View Release Notes" id="package2_viewReleaseNotes" data-package="releaseNotes">
 <input type="button" name="View Runtime Log" value="View Runtime Log" id="package2_viewLog">
     <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
       $("#package2_viewLog").click(function() {viewLog("---", "---", "no")});
 });
   </script>


   <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#package2_enable").click(function() {appControl("---", "---", "enable",  "no")});
 });
   </script>
     <input type="button" name="Enable" value="Enable" id="package2_enable">



 <input type="button" name="Uninstall" value="Uninstall" id="package2_uninstall">
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("#package2_uninstall").click(function() {appControl("---", "---", "uninstall", "no")});
 });
 </script>

   </div>
 </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: is your url public?

Comment: No url is not public.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All these error messages...

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element
```

and

```
Element is not clickable at point . Other element would receive the click
```

...implies that you are invoking the `click()` even before the [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/) or [AJAX](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)  Call completely renders the element and the complete [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes).

---

### Solution

You need to induce *WebDriverWait* for the desired `element_to_be_clickable()` as follows:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until( EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, element_xpath))).click()
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I was giving webdriver wait when clicking on the collapse-able element but did not give wait on clicking for this new exposed element. It worked like a charm. You have been really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned when you do it manually you are clicking twice on expand button.
Try action and double click event.see if you get any luck.

```
ActionChains(driver).move_to_element(element).double_click(element).perform()
```

OR

```
ActionChains(driver).double_click(element).perform()
```

You need to have following imports.

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
```

Comment: I am sorry if I was not clear in explaining it. So the div is supposed to be expanded in a single click and collapse with second click when doing manually. When I am doing with selenium it looks like it is clicking it twice already so that it expands the div and soon after closed it too, which is visible as test runs. I however tried your above solution but it does not work.

Comment: try with click(element) instead of double_click(element)

Comment: with click() it works exactly as it was working before with:

```WebDriverWait(self.driver, 20).until(
            EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, css_selector))).click()```